# How to properly evaluate etimedout requests in Artillery.io report

Tags: testing, performance-testing, load-testing, artillery

I tested Artillery.io (cloud-scale load testing) against a page which I believe should work seamlessly: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) :)

I'm now wondering if Artillery is reliable. I got 47 errors.ETIMEDOUT out of 600 http requests.

How is this possible, am I missing something? I would have expected 0 time out requests.

```
npm install -g artillery 
artillery run landing-page-test.json
```

```
// landing-page-test.json

{
  "config": {
    "target": "https://wwww.google.com/",
    "phases": [
      {
        "duration": 60,
        "arrivalRate": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  "scenarios": [
    {
      "name": "Load test landing page",
      "flow": [
        {
          "get": {
            "url": "/"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**ARTILLERY.IO REPORT:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Artillery will set the timeout of the requests [to be 10s by default](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/http#request-timeouts). If some of your requests are taking longer than that, you will get `ETIMEDOUT` errors - so this might be the reason.

You can see in your final results that the p99 is around 3.3s, indicating that there were already a few of the requests taking longer. It's possible those other 47 requests took over 10s, and were therefore timing out.

This could be due to bandwidth/network issues from where you ran Artillery. For example, I just ran your script and had no `ETIMEDOUT` errors, and a p99 of 1.5s (and my signal is actually not very strong at the moment).

P.S. It might also be that Google intentionally detects and slows down high enough RPS. I know if you go high enough with `arrivalRate`, you'll start getting rate limited, for example.